# Space between the View pager and tabLayout which is inside collpasing toolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Some empty space is shown after `tab Layout`. I have the view pager outside the app bar layout and tab layout inside the Relative Layout which is inside of collapsing toolbar. Not able to determine from where this extra space is added. Any help would be appreciated. The hierarchy of the views is Coordinator, App Bar, Collapsing Toolbar, Frame Layout, Relative Layout, Tab Layout.
Below is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_bg"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/header_picture"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/splash"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_profile_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                        android:text="Kunal Bagla"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="19dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_profile_location"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_profile_name"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Udaipur"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_settings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/black_border_rounded"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Settings"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_profile_location"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
                       />


                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/drawee_avatar"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/home_bg"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:roundAsCircle="true" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/drawee_camera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="camera"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_sub_main_dice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/menu_icon_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_app_icon"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_login_logout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Some empty space is shown after tab Layout.
```

Specyfy what u meen ( is there inside of tab layout or outside the best print printscreen)
Is there only in 1 place this extra space or in all AppBarLayout

And u modify in activities those items?

I woud check first behavior those layout at solo and add 1 by 1 next items and then u probly see what's wrong and abou

Comment: Hey thanks but the space seems to be because of the height specified in appbar layout. Now reducing causes the top image to shrink. By the way thanks for responding to the issue.

Comment: I will post a complete solution so that in future if some one requires this behavior its available. I am working on it since 4-5 days. Hope some one gets help from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if required by some one else. If you want your toolbar to be fixed and content to be scrolled under use collapse mode as pin for toolbar and scrollFlags as scroll|exitAlwaysCollapsed for collapsing toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_bg"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
     app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_product"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/splash" />

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/drawee_avatar"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_product"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_product"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/home_bg"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:roundAsCircle="true" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/drawee_camera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="camera"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </FrameLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:text="XYZ"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_view_product"    />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_profile_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_profile_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/black_border_rounded"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_view_product" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_profile_location"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_profile_location"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_sub_main_dice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_icon_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_app_icon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_login_logout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```